# Creating a shared library in C

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a shared library in C with the following file structure.

In `func1.h`

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_FUNC1_H_
#define INCLUDE_FUNC1_H_

void function1();

#endif
```

In `func1.c`

```
#include "func1.h"

void function1() {
    //do function 1
}
```

In `func2.h`

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_FUNC2_H_
#define INCLUDE_FUNC2_H_

void function2();

#endif
```

In `func2.c`

```
#include "func2.h"

void function2() {
    //do function 2
}
```

Now to avoid having to include multiple header files, I want a common header file, `commonheader.h` which includes the other header files.

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_COMMONHEADER_H_
#define INCLUDE_COMMONHEADER_H_

#include "func1.h"
#include "func2.h"

#endif
```

Next I compiled them into a shared library as so.

```
gcc -c -fPIC -o func1.o func1.c
gcc -c -fPIC -o func2.o func2.c
gcc -shared -o libcommonheader.so *.o
```

Now I'm trying to use the shared library created. `test.c` looks like this,

```
#include "commonheader.h"
int main () {
    function1();
}
```

I tried to compiled this with,

```
gcc -L. -I. -Wall -o test test.c -lcommonheader
```

However it returns with error undefined reference to `function1'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in C a function declaration like `void function2();` doesn't mean that you declare that `function2` takes no arguments. For that you need to use `void function2(void);`. If you don't have `void` as "argument", you say that the function can take any number of unknown arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the problem was with a global variable that had been declared incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple typo: your functions are called `function*`, rather than `func*`.

Please note that with `-Wall` (that you mentioned) you should be seeing the following warning which indicates the problem (at least with `gcc >= 4.8`):

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func1’; did you mean ‘function1’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     func1();
     ^~~~~
     function1
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have the function name correct.